# Grid with dynamic width and dynamic number of item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a grid and I've been looking at several solutions with Flexbox and CSS Grid but none of these solutions will work for me which is why I'm posting this.

I have a container, which can be resized to a max and min width. And the items inside have fixed widths but it's **not always the same**. As in, I want to reuse the grid so that it aligns anything I put in there.

This is my expected result:

[image]
[image]

I don't want to use CSS Grid because I need it to support really old versions of Chrome and Firefox and Safari.

I tried using Flexbox with justify-content space-around and ended up with this:
[image]

I found several solutions such as adding trailing invisible items. But it's a solution that's being rejected by our review process.

How do I achieve this layout? I'm using Angular 4 and I'm open to any Javascript/CSS based solutions. Strictly no Jquery.

EDIT: I want the behaviour to be similar to justify-content: space-between but as I've mentioned before, the solution to fix the last row is not accepted by my superiors.

Comment: Could you give example pictures when the items don't have same width?

Comment: @Cons7an7ine Hi. By different I meant, if an item is 30px in width, then all items inside that container would be 30px in width. But in another container using the same grid an item can be 100px in width, then all the items in that container will be 100px in width. What I was trying to say is, the solution should not be bound to the content's size. So the image above it applicable to all scenarios.

Comment: You mean there will be no instance that container will contain items with different widths at one time?

Comment: @Cons7an7ine Yes. item size is different between two different containers. But within a single container all the items are in the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use floated boxes as children of a container with variable width, for this.

Here's a snippet to show how that would work:

```css
.container {
  width: 450px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container-2 {
  width: 350px;
}

.container-3 {
  width: 250px;
}

.container-4 {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div> 
  
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>

<div class="container container-2">
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div> 
  
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>

<div class="container container-3">
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div> 
  
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>

<div class="container container-4">
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div>  
  <div class="child"></div> 
  
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Note the last element `<div style="clear: both"></div>` in each container is merely meant to ensure that the container gets required height automatically.

[Codepen] : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXMXma

Comment: I actually want the boxes to be evenly spaced. :( So in the last container, "container-4", the boxes would be centered to the container. Just like how justify-content in flex would work. I should mention that in my question.

Comment: @user3607282 I can't think of anything that supports it wihout javascript, other than Flexbox.